# Can't get rid of light gray color when srcoll ends

Tags: java, android

So I'm using xml layout like below to get tablayout scrollable. thing is is that when it reaches end it creates that annoying light color and cannot get rid of it. Any help is welcome. fadingEdge does nothing

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

[image]

Comment: can you pride a link to an image of what you mean?

Comment: @tyczj  https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-DNlAzPm9igE/VcUYEaJ_uSI/AAAAAAAAAuk/p1C5S1qO0dY/w506-h900/Screenshot_2015-08-07-22-19-44.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, well well....

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

is now deprecated, use

`android:overScrollMode="never"`

hope this will help.

Comment: @HenryAlbatras Perfect